# Excel: Searching for multiple terms at the beginning of a cell

Tags: excel, function, search

I have a spreadsheet of numbers that I am looking to search what the first 5 digits of the number are and then apply a certain filter based off of that.

I currently have the following which I have gotten based off of similar StackOverflow topics, but the issue I am having is that I only want the "BlahBlah" to apply when the cell in the A column starts with any of those 5 digit numbers, instead I am getting those that start with those 5 digits, but the "BlahBlah" is applying to values where the 5 digit number is in the middle of the A column cell so for instance it will apply it on numbers like 982*12345*7548 or 7838*23456*883

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({12345,23456,34567},$A2)),"BlahBlah","")
```

The SEARCH function should return the number of the location where the string starts, so I tried doing something like the following, but it returns a value error.

```
=IF(SEARCH({12345,23456,34567},$A2)=1,"BlahBlah","")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, try:

```
 =IF(OR({12345,23456,34567}=--LEFT(A1,5)),"BlahBlah","")
```

This should work regardless of whether the item in column A is a string or a number.

[image]

Comment: I should have specified that the numbers I am looking for won't always be the same length, some might be 5 digits long, others might be 6 or 7, etc. When trying the above on my data I see it working for some, but if I have a long number in the left column that starts with 12345 it won't pick it up. Any idea why?

Comment: @WilsonTim123 Without seeing the number, and knowing what you mean by "long", I have no idea.  The numbers in my example are of different lengths, and the one starting with 12345 seems to be "long"

Comment: I think I see what I was doing wrong with the numbers being long issue, it looks like it was formatting, is there a way I could use multiple LEFT() statements since some of the numbers I will be looking for vary in length and won't all be 5 in length?

Comment: @WilsonTim123 Without examples truly representative of your data, I would hesitate to recommend anything. Why not show a set of representative examples? The formula would work on the strings you have shown in your question :  `982*12345*7548` or `7838*23456*883`, none of which start with your required numbers.